# how to grant privileges on a database without table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how to grant privileges on a database without table.

I've tried the following:

GRANT ALL ON databasename to username@hostname;

and it shows me an error saying "can't find any matching row in the user table".

Comment: Well, does the user name exist?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ not programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried something of this sort,

```
mysql> create database amarokdb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant usage on *.* to amarokuser@localhost identified by 'amarokpasswd';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on amarokdb.* to amarokuser@localhost ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The problem is that i don't want to set privileges to all database. I guess if I try grant usage on *.* to amarokuser@localhost identified by 'amarokpasswd'; would set at least permission to use all database. am I right??

Comment: @user722756, when you use  `amarokdb.*` that grants only on that DB. If you use `*.*` then it is for all DBs

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your server has the NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER mode enabled.

From the MySQL manual: (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html)

> NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER prevents the GRANT statement from automatically
>   creating new users if it would otherwise do so, unless a nonempty
>   password also is specified. (Added in MySQL 5.0.2)

So you can either remove the NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER mode or create the user WITH a password like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON databasename TO username@hostname IDENTIFIED BY 'your non-empty password here'
```